# Probability that the first person to be done with the test will leave after at most 41 minutes?

Tags: probability

Assume that the amount of time it takes for a student to finish a Math 425 midterm is a random 
variable with uniform distribution between 40 and 60 minutes.

Suppose that there are 130 people in the class. What is 
the probability that the first person to be done with the test will leave after at most 41 minutes?

How do you account for it to be that first person? Where do I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the students are i.i.d. - Then, student $i$'s waiting time is Uniform(40,60), call this $U_i$. Then, you want $$P(min(U_1,\ldots,U_{130}) \leq 41) \\
= 1 - P(min(U_1, \ldots, U_{130} )> 41) = 1 - P( U_1 > 41, U_2 > 41, \ldots, U_{130}>41)$$

Now, use iid to get that $P(U_1>41, \ldots, U_{130}>41) = \prod_i P(U_i > 41) = P(U_1 > 41)^{130}$

Comment: Okay... I'm still a little confused. Forgetting the 130 students for a minute, I believe that the P(x > 41) = 0.95, correct?

Comment: Where is $X$ in this? $U_i$ is the time for the $i$-th student to finish, so $\min_i U_i$ is the time the first student finishes. Then, you're just using the fact that $P(\min_i U_i > c) = P(U_1 > c, U_2 > c , \ldots)$ and using i.i.d.-ness of the $U_i$ to turn that into $P(U_i > c)^n$ where there are $n$ students.

Comment: The x was just a place holder, really. P(U_i > 41) = 0.95 though, isn't it? Cause if so then you would take that value to the 130th... But the homework says it is incorrect.

Comment: You're concerned with $P(\min(U_1,\ldots,U_{130}) \leq 41)$. Look at my answer.

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense now. Got it. Thank you!